# Asynchronous call during a synchronous CasperJS operation

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, phantomjs, screen-scraping, casperjs

After allot of trouble (first timer nodejs and casperjs/phantomjs) it started to work. I made this work with curl(php).

This is what I try to accomplish:

1. Log in
2. Get all units
3. parse their details
4. **(my problem) 2 unit details are provided by ajax calls**

```
casper.start(url, function() {
      this.evaluate(function() {
          document.querySelector("input[name='username']").value = "username";
          document.querySelector("input[name='password']").value = "passwrd";
          document.querySelector("#login").click();
     });
     console.log("Logged in..");
});

var processPage = function() {
    console.log("Get all units..");
    var units = this.evaluate(getUnits);
    allUnits.push(units);

    if (!this.evaluate(isLastPage)) {
        this.thenClick('.paging li:last-child a').then(function() {
            currentPage++;
            console.log("Stepping to page.. " + currentPage);
            this.waitFor(function() {
                return currentPage === this.evaluate(getSelectedPage);
            }, processPage, terminate);
        });
    } else{
        require('utils').dump(allUnits);
        casper.then(function() {
             this.capture('test.png');
        });
        console.log("Total unit count: " + allUnits.length);
    }
};



 casper.waitForSelector('.units', processPage, terminate);
 casper.run();
```

In the following function I parse the rows and I want to add the 2 details that are fetched by ajax too but i dont know how to do it. (async)

```
function getUnits() {
    var rows = document.querySelectorAll('.units');
    var units = [];

    for (var i = 0, row; row = rows[i]; i++) {
        var aID = row.querySelector('a').getAttribute('href').split('/');
        unit['id'] = aID[2];
        //add other details for the unit

        **//Do a async call to the 2 external links with the ID and add the details to the unit**

        units.push(unit);
    } 

    return units;

};
```

What is important to note is that at the end i want to run another function on the units but all must be already fetched by then before running it...

**EDIT**

After login the page shows a table and I am getting that table its like this

- ID
- OWNER
- STREET
- BEINGFOLLOWED
  (automatic ajax call that is done to a link with post)
- PLACEDABIDON (automatic ajax call that is done to a link with
  post)

I tried to get the last 2 fields with casper normally but sometimes it got the value and sometimes it didnt (request sometimes too slow)

Want I wanted to know is how can you get these fields without waiting for each row(unit) till it got the value. (So every unit should get the values for them selfs and fill them in their object. So probably a callback is needed ?

Or i can do the request my self i just need the ID and the cookie to do the post (the link takes the ID and Cookie as parameter) and get the details and fill it in but I dont know how to do that or if the first solution works better or even if this is possible...

The most important thing is that after all units have their details it should continue with the app's logic...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since PhantomJS (and CasperJS) has two contexts, it is easy to break out of the execution flow.

I see two ways to solve your problem.

## 1. Send the request yourself

You need to trigger the requests inside of the page context (inside of `evaluate()`) and let the outer context wait for the result. I assume that you can have a success callback in the page context.

You have to put the result of the external requests somewhere global so that the outer context can get to it. For example, modify your `getUnits()` function like this:

```
function getUnits() {
    var rows = document.querySelectorAll('.units');
    var units = [];
    window.__externalRequestResults = [[], []];

    for (var i = 0, row; row = rows[i]; i++) {
        var aID = row.querySelector('a').getAttribute('href').split('/');
        unit['id'] = aID[2];
        //add other details for the unit

        //Do a async call to the 2 external links with the ID and add the details to the unit
        (function(i){
            var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xhr.open("GET", someURLwithParameters, true);
            xhr.onreadystatechange = function(){
                if (xhr.readyState === 4) { // DONE
                    __externalRequestResults[0][i] = xhr.responseText;
                }
            };

            xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xhr.open("GET", someOtherURLwithParameters, true);
            xhr.onreadystatechange = function(){
                if (xhr.readyState === 4) { // DONE
                    __externalRequestResults[1][i] = xhr.responseText;
                }
            };
            xhr.send();
        })(i);

        units.push(unit);
    } 

    return units;
};
```

Now you can retrieve the immediate results and then wait for additional results:

```
var processPage = function() {
    console.log("Get all units..");
    var units = this.evaluate(getUnits);
    var numberOfRows = this.getElementsInfo("table tr").length; // TODO: fix selector
    var externalUnits;
    this.waitFor(function test(){
        externalUnits = this.getGlobal("__externalRequestResults");
        for(var i = 0; i < numberOfRows; i++) {
            if (externalUnits[0][i] == null || externalUnits[1][i] == null) {
                return false
            }
        }
        return true;
    }, function _then(){
        allUnits.push(units);
        allUnits.push(externalUnits); // TODO: maybe a little differently

        if (!this.evaluate(isLastPage)) {
            //... as before
        } else{
            //... as before
        }
    }, terminate);
};
```

The end of the waiting period is triggered when the number of both lists of additional data is the same size as the table has number of rows and all are filled. This creates a sparse array and `Array#push()` cannot be used, because the different Ajax requests may come in a different ordering than in which they were sent.

## 2. Let the browser handle the request

In the second case you let CasperJS wait for all data to come in. The challenge is to write a check function that does this.

```
var processPage = function() {
    console.log("Get all units..");
    var numberOfRows = this.getElementsInfo("table tr").length; // TODO: fix selector
    this.waitFor(function test(){
        var data1, data2;
        for(var i = 1; i <= numberOfRows; i++) {
            data1 = this.fetchText("table tr:nth-child("+i+") td:nth-child(4)") || "";
            data2 = this.fetchText("table tr:nth-child("+i+") td:nth-child(5)") || "";
            if (data1.trim() === "" || data2.trim() === "") {
                return false
            }
        }
        return true;
    }, function _then(){
        var units = this.evaluate(getUnits);
        allUnits.push(units);

        if (!this.evaluate(isLastPage)) {
            //... as before
        } else{
            //... as before
        }
    }, terminate);
};
```

Now, you don't even need to make Ajax requests inside `getUnits()` and can simply collect all the static information.

Don't forget to make the failed waiting timeout big enough that all Ajax requests complete in time. For example 3 or 4 times larger than the normal time for all ajax requests to load. You can use the global [`casper.options.waitTimeout`](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/modules/casper.html#waittimeout) for that.

Comment: It's still not clear how to do the call to another page... Because calling Casper inside the function doesn't work..can you show how you do that ?

Comment: I was under the impression that you're doing an ajax call. What you want now is something completely different.

Comment: The page that is loaded has some details I need but 2 are called through Ajax from another page (checked in network) maybe I need to wait a bit longer to get them also ? So maybe I need the async callback like you said right ?

Comment: So the page itself does those requests? If so, then you would somehow need to catch the result. PhantomJS can observe the requests, but doesn't expose the contents of those.

Comment: After the login the page shows immediately 6 fields for each unit but 2 fields are sometimes not showing because they are being fetched by an ajax call(sometimes its slow).So my question is how to get them with casperjs. In php curl i did sync call to the url (the ajax call) for each unit to fill in the details. To make sure i got them instead of waiting for them to display. But it was slow because I had to wait for reach unit before contiuing to the next..so i want to do it async.But after all the units it needs to be done before continueing the rest of the flow (I use the data in the logic)

Comment: PhantomJS is supposed to behave like a normal browser. So you need to do the same thing in CasperJS that you would do in Chrome for example. I don't know how the Ajax requests are triggered. If they appear after some click, then you need to click and wait until the additional rows appear in the DOM. If it is triggered by itself, then you simply wait for them to appear in the DOM. If I misunderstood you and the data doesn't appear in the DOM, then please clarify your question. I don't want to play the [guessing game](https://blog.stackexchange.com/2012/02/lets-play-the-guessing-game/) anymore.

Comment: If you don't want to do this through the browser, but actually want to send those requests yourself, then you're on your own, because you haven't shown any details and every page is different. I've done my best to describe how you would do that in the general case.

Comment: I updated the post with some extra information to clear up the doubts you have maybe i am still stuck in my old way of thinking about programming thats why sometimes i try to follow a solution that is maybe too much trouble.

Comment: Your edit was rejected, because you erroneously edited my answer instead of your question.

Comment: this is what happens if you dont get enough sleep and cant figure stuff out :/ fail

Comment: Ok, you say you successfully accessed the ajax resources with CURL. That means that you can access them in a similar fashion with `XMLHttpRequest`. I've updated my answer with a clearer example. I also added another way of doing this without making Ajax requests yourself.

Comment: I will try both and let you know how this works out and which one is faster. Beside that I have a qq question out of interest. I see you use the waitselector. Is it possible to use that in the getUnits for loop ? So during a row scrape wait on the value for that specific row ?

Comment: No. You can't use any `casper` functions inside of `casper.evaluate()`, because the page context is sandboxed. You can't use variables defined outside and you can't pass non-serializable variables in.

Comment: Didnt get the second function working only the first one. I got into another issue callback is not firing in the casper.then. will create a new issue. thanks for the help learned allot

Comment: Well, for the second option, I assume that the table cells are empty or contain whitespace before they are loaded. It is also possible that you've run into a bug, because if you're using PhantomJS 1.x the `:nth-child()` selector doesn't work sometimes. The workaround would be to use XPath expressions.